# Hair appearing in Object Mode when removed in Particle Edit

Tags: objects, particles, hair

[image: In Object Mode.]
[image: In Particle Edit.]

Hair appears on the underside of this beak in Object Mode even after I have removed it in particle edit. I have it set to "interpolated" with 40 children per parent. When I look inside of the beak, there is hair at the top facing down, too. How do I remove this hair?

Comment: By default, children are not displayed in Particle Edit/Comb mode. If there is hair inside the beak then I would check the face orientation (flipped normals). You also can define a vertex group for the density of the hair. It's in the settings of the Particle System. If you exclude the beak from the vertex group, no more hair should grow there.